# How to detect highlighted <option> in a drop-down menue?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I'm looking for a solution beside mouseover so the detection is also effective with arrow up/down button.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you asking about `<select>` element or some custom implementation?

Comment: That's right. I probably need to edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: Would `onfocus` work?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the change event - http://api.jquery.com/change/ which will be triggered when the selected value changes

```
$("select").change(function (){});
```

Comment: Change only works when the selection is complete. I need to detect the state before that when user is just browsing the options with up and down key or hover.